# How can one get newsletter from ubuntu?

Tags: community

I think that every big open source projects has it's news letter.
How to receive Ubuntu related news information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a link to the Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-news